# Capturar ID com eloquent no JOIN

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Boa tarde a todos, tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
$acordo = tb_acordo::join('users', 'users_id', '=', 'users.id')
                            ->join('tb_status_acordos', 'tb_status_acordos_id', '=', 'tb_status_acordos.id')
                            ->join('tb_carteiras', 'tb_carteira_id', '=', 'tb_carteiras.id')
                            ->where('users_id', $id_user )
                            ->orderBy('data_acordo', 'desc')
                            ->get();
```

Porém no view quando captudo o ID desta forma: `{{$acordos->id}}` ele me trás o ID da tabela users e preciso da tabela tb_acordo, alguém ajuda com essa consulta por favor?

Comment: Você pode usar o `->select()`, da uma olhada no link da documentação https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

Comment: Cara, me esqueci do Select, consegui muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só para encerrar o tópico.

> Você pode nem sempre querer selecionar todas as colunas de uma tabela de banco de dados. Usando o método select, você pode especificar uma cláusula de seleção personalizada para a consulta:

Pode se usar o :
`->selecte()`

Para poder informar quais os campos você deseja realmente ver.

Segue o link da documentação.[select()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins)